# Where is Microsoft Connect App in Windows 10 - 2004

Tags: windows-10-v2004

I'v done a fresh install of Windows 10-v2004. Realised that Microsoft Connect App is missing.
Windows 10-v2004 still had this app. Checked two PC with 5Ghz WiFi cards, this app is missing.
Did Microsoft drop this application, could some else confirm, on fresh install this application is missing please?

Answer (score 0):

It is present, but I have no idea why Microsoft made it and optional resource:

1. Press Start then search Manage optional features
2. Click Add then on the list > select Wireless Display
3. Check the box then Install

Hope it helps.